# How to solve memory issue in MATLAB - How to increase memory and max array length?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have HDF files of Chlorophyll data. I am trying to process these HDF4 files to generate NDVI for the period. but when I try to execute

```
Band = hdfread('F:\MATLAB\HDF data\binned hdf\OCMHDFFiles_20-Sep-2012\O2_01APR2011_004_000_GAN_L3B_CL_M.hdf','clo','Fields','');
% Construct an RGB matrix from the three bands into one 3D matrix.
SPCrater_321 = cat(Band);
% Display the image
figure(1)
imshow(SPCrater_321)
xlabel('Longitude (pixels)')
ylabel('Latitude (pixels)')
title('ASTER Bands 3, 2, 1')
??? Error using ==> permute
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
Error in ==> hdfsdsread at 57
data = permute(data,ndims(data):-1:1);
Error in ==> hdfread at 240
varargout{1} = hdfsdsread(hinfo,start,stride,edge);
```

Next execution is,

```
Band_3 = hdfread('F:\MATLAB\HDF data\binned hdf\OCMHDFFiles_20-Sep-2012\O2_01APR2011_004_000_GAN_L3B_CL_M.hdf','clo','Fields','ImageData3N');
Band_2 = hdfread('F:\MATLAB\HDF data\binned hdf\OCMHDFFiles_20-Sep-2012\O2_01APR2011_004_000_GAN_L3B_CL_M.hdf','clo','Fields','ImageData2');
Band_1 = hdfread('F:\MATLAB\HDF data\binned hdf\OCMHDFFiles_20-Sep-2012\O2_01APR2011_004_000_GAN_L3B_CL_M.hdf','clo','Fields','ImageData1');
% Calculate NDVI.
Band_2 = im2single(Band_2);
Band_3 = im2single(Band_3);
SPCrater_NDVI = (Band_3 - Band_2) ./ (Band_3 + Band_2);
% Display the image.
j=imresize(SPCrater_NDVI,0.5);
figure(5)
imshow(j,'DisplayRange',[0 1])
??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

And this is what I get when I type the 'memory' command at this point of execution:

```
memory
Maximum possible array:             255 MB (2.669e+008 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:    569 MB (5.971e+008 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:             1197 MB (1.255e+009 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):             8181 MB (8.578e+009 bytes)
*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

can anyone please help me to solve this issue. how to increase the length of the memory array.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.
I will be grateful if you can send me this information.

M. Prabu

(maprabu)

Comment: It looks like you're running on Windows ? Is it 32 bit or 64 bit Windows ?

Comment: yes i am using windows xp 32 bit. 8gb of ram. is there any solution to solve this problem

Comment: First, use the /3GB swwitch, as described in the technote linked in my answer. That, however, won't increase the size of the maximum array.

Comment: You probably need to go to a 64 bit OS, preferably a proper OS, but a 64 bit version of Windows should work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this technote: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html?s_tid=doc_12b#brh72ex-52

The most straightforward solution is to go 64 bits.